# vhdl instruction requires: Not 64-bit mode

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I'm using ghdl (open source compiler for vhdl) on mac.
I write this simple half adder component :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ha is 

    port( 
        a:  in  std_logic;
        b:  in  std_logic;
        o:  out     std_logic;
        c:  out     std_logic
    );

end ha;

architecture behave of ha is 
begin

    o <= a xor b;
    c <= a and b;

end behave;
```

when I want to analyze the ha.vhdl component (using -a switch) with command below, I get a lot of following error:

command:
`ghdl -a ha.vhdl`

errors:

`ha.s:90:2: error: instruction requires: Not 64-bit mode`

`pushl   %ebp`

`ha.s:103:2: error: instruction requires: Not 64-bit mode`

`pushl   %edx`

.
.
.

Comment: Please report this bug on [GHDL's GitHub](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/) page and create a [bug report](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/issues/new?template=bug_report.md). Please include the GHDL version, operating system and backend you are using.

Comment: `pushl   %ebp` is a 32-bit x86 instruction.  It won't assemble in 64-bit mode because there's no way to encode a 32-bit operand size for `push` or `pop` in 64-bit mode.  (And you wouldn't want to only push the 32-bit low half of RBP anyway: this is clearly 32-bit asm source which you (or GHDL) should assemble in 32-bit mode)

Comment: which version of ghdl? Which compiler backend? Which OS? If reasonably recent (0.34 or newer) see Paebbels comment, otherwise upgrade...

Comment: You can download a newer version of ghdl for OS X from the [Github Repository](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/releases). The macosx mcode and llvm versions for ghdl-0.35 are both functional and accept your code. You can see there's some interest in the version history of the ghdl your operating system.

Comment: @Paebbels thank you... I will do it

Comment: @PeterCordes you mean it is not possible to compile this code on MacOs 64-bit?(or other 64-bit machines)

Comment: @BrianDrummond as I mentioned it is on macOs. my ghdl version is 0.24. I will update it to newer version... thank you.

Comment: @user1155120 thank you so much. I will update it. :D

Comment: ghdl has come a LONG way since 0.24. Don't bother with the bug report unless you still see troubles with an upgraded version.